# Getting error in VS2008 No source code available for the current location

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using VS2008. I have asp button where I am trying to call javascript function on "Onclientclick" event and .cs code in "onclick event". When I run the project it gets build successfully, but throws error "No Source code available for the current location".

I also noticed that when I remove the javascript code, my project works properly.

Please suggest.

Comment: please add the relevant code.

Comment: paste code with screen shot of error message.

Comment: As well, Check browser console for errors

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Font-Bold="true"
        BackColor="#66FF99" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="if (!validate()) { return false;};" />

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var Firstname,LastName;
function validate() 
{
    Firstname = document.getElementById('<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value;
    LastName = document.getElementById('<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>').value;

    if (Firstname == "") 
    {
        alert("Enter First Name");
        return false;
    }
    
    if (LastName == "") 
    {
        alert("Enter Last Name");
        return false;
    }
    
    }
    </script>